# how to install ubuntu on part of the disk?

Tags: partition, system-installation

I have new laptop with 500 giga hardisk size.
I want to install 3 kind of Linux distribution.

The first linux will be ubuntu.

Now, i want that the installation of the ubuntu will take over only 100 gb and i don't know how to do it.

I load the machine from the disk and i choose 'install ubuntu' and i waiting on the 'installation type' screen.

I case chose the option of creating or resize the partition be my self - but i don't know what to do next.

please any help

Comment: you're going to use gparted or parted   (partitioning programs) to partition the hard drive. There are many ways to partition a drive for linux, so you should look online for linux partition schemes

Answer (score 1):

These simplest what of doing this is to boot your system using Ubuntu bootable USB and open gparted app.
There you can do partitioning in the way you like.

Remember, you cannot have more than 4 primary partition. If you need more, you must make one extended partition which gives you option for making other partitions withing it.

By having a simple search in web you can find good tips for partitioning.

Comment: Remember to make one partition for swap. It is suggested to keep it double of your RAM but maximum 8GB.

Comment: There is only a  primary partition limit of four if the OP installs an old style MBR.